# Prolog - generate crosswords

Tags: prolog, crossword

I'm facing this difficult exercise, I already saw other exercises about crosswords (i.e. the last exercise of "p-99: ninety-nine prolog programs", or the one reported in "Prolog programming for AI" by Bratko), but this is different and more difficult, because here we don't have any template to fill.

**Text**:

Write a Prolog program to generate a crossword. Suppose you have a dictionary of facts like this: w(Word,Lentgth). Write a predicate crossword(C,W,H) to instantiate C, to all possible list (crossword) of lists (crossword row) of character of the dictionary, where a black cell is represented by an asterisk.
Example:

```
w(online,6).
w(prolog,6).
w(perl,5).
w(emacs,5).
w(linux,5).
w(gnu,3).
w(mac,3).
w(nfs,3).
w(sql,3).
w(web,3).
w(xml,3).
w(a,1).
w(b,1).
w(e,1).
w(i,1).
w(l,1).
w(m,1).
w(n,1).
w(o,1).
w(q,1).
w(r,1).
w(s,1).
w(t,1).
w(u,1).
w(w,1).

?- crossword(C,9,6).
C=[[p,r,o,l,o,g,*,*,e],
   [e,*,n,*,*,n,*,*,m],
   [r,*,l,i,n,u,x,*,a],
   [l,*,i,*,f,*,m,a,c],
   [*,*,n,*,s,q,l,*,s],
   [*,w,e,b,*,*,*,*,*]]
```

**Given Hints**

1) You could add to the dictionary these "black" words:

```
black(*,1).
black(**,2).
black(***,3).
black(****,4).
black(*****,5).
```

2) Each row is sequence of "white" words (normal words) and "black" words interleaved, and this sequence can begin/finish with both.

3) I suggest you to manage the 2 possibility of the previous point with 2 different clause.

4) A crossword is a matrix of character, so its transpose is still a crossword.

5) The transpose crossword is already instantiated, so you only have to check its feasibility with the dictionary.

This is what came in my mind: create a list of H (heigh of crossword, row) lists (the rows of the crossword), for each list (row) I try to insert words from the dictionary followed by "black" words and then again a word, until the row is full, or the same thing starting from a "black". When the the crossword is full, I transpose it and check is the transpose is a valid crossword too: each word contained is a valid word from the dictionary.
I know this is a very inefficient method, I tried with a little dictionary to generate crossword 2x2, it generates correctly the firsts two, but seem to take years for the third. I don't know if there is something wrong in my code, maybe it gets stuck somewhere. Do you know a more efficient way to solve this problem or you see something to be improved in my code?

```
crossword(C,W,H):- create(C,H),
                   insert_words(C,W,[],_),
                   clpfd:transpose(C,Traspose),
                   isok(Traspose).

insert_words([],_,U,U).
insert_words([H|T],W,Uacc,U):-
                             (add_white(H,[],C,[],Uacc,Udef);
                              add_black(H,[],C,[],Uacc,Udef)),
                              insert_words(T,C,Udef,U).

create(Puzzle,H) :- length(Puzzle,H).


add_white(P,P,0,_,U,U).
add_white(P,Row,R,Used,Uacc,Udef):- 
                                R\=0,
                                w(Word,L),
                                \+member(Word,Used),
                                \+member(Word,Uacc),
                                R2 is R-L,
                                R2 >= 0,
                                atom_chars(Word,Word2),
                                append(Row,Word2,Row2),
                                append(Used,[Word],Used2),
                                append(Uacc,[Word],Uacc2),
                                add_black(P,Row2,R2,Used2,Uacc2,Udef).

add_white(P,Row,R,Used,Uacc,Udef):-
                                   R\=0,
                                   w(Word,L),
                                   \+member(Word,Used),
                                   R2 is R-L,
                                   R2 < 0,
                                   append(Used,[Word],Used2),
                                   add_white(P,Row,R,Used2,Uacc,Udef).

add_white(P,Row,R,Used,Uacc,Udef):-
                                   R\=0,
                                   w(Word,_),
                                   member(Word,Used),
                                   add_white(P,Row,R,Used,Uacc,Udef).


add_black(P,P,0,_,U,U).
add_black(P,Row,R,Used,Uacc,Udef):-
                                   R\=0,
                                   black(Black,L),
                                   R2 is R-L,
                                   R2 >= 0,
                                   atom_chars(Black,Black2),
                                   append(Row,Black2,Row2),
                                   add_white(P,Row2,R2,Used,Uacc,Udef).

add_black(P,Row,R,Used,Uacc,Udef):-
                                   R\=0,
                                   black(_,L),
                                   R2 is R-L,
                                   R2 < 0,
                                   add_black(P,Row,R,Used,Uacc,Udef).

isok([]).
isok([H|T]):-split(H,*,R),
        check(R),
        isok(T).

split(L,C,R):-split2(L,C,X),trim(X,R).

split2(In, Sep, [Left|Rest]) :-
append(Left, [Sep|Right], In), !, split2(Right, Sep, Rest).
split2(In, _Sep, [In]).

trim([],[]).
trim([H|T],[H|T2]):-H\=[],trim(T,T2).
trim([H|T],Y):-H=[],trim(T,Y).

check([]).
check([H|T]):-
               atom_chars(X,H),
               w(X,_),
               check(T).
```

I'm using this little dictionary, instead of the original one, to test my program and generate simple 2x2 crosswords, but as I said before it seems to get stuck after correctly found 2 solutions.

```
w(ci,2).
w(ca,2).
w(i,1).
w(a,1).
black(*,1).
```

Comment: all those tests like `\+member(Word,Used)` are really inefficient. A small gain would come from using memberchk/2 instead of member/2. Better gain would come from using sorted data structures, or hashtables

Comment: this bug could harm the entire solution: `w(perl,5).` should be `w(perl,4).`. BTW, why add to database such irrelevant information as the atom length ? You can get it with - duh - `?- atom_length(perl,L).`

Comment: This was the original text of the exercise, it was said the length added to simplify, but I agree to you that it's not necessary. BTW to test my program I'm not using the original dictionary, but a reduced one, to produce a 2x2 crossword fast, I'm going to edit my question to clarify it. What about what you said in the previous comment? I don't know at all hashtables, can you give some information or a link to start with? thank you

Comment: Well, since you didn't stated the Prolog you're using, I avoided concrete references to libraries. Hashtables can be implemented in Prolog as any other languages, **if** it offers support for unlimited arity structures, and an hashing facility. But first, just try to replace member/2 with memberchk/2...

Comment: this call `insert_words(C,W,[],_),` is suspicious: why the output variable is unused ? maybe it's what should passed down...

Comment: I'm using swi-prolog. Tried with memberchk/2, without noticeable improvements.
My output variable is `C`, the last parameter `_` represents the words used in the entire crossword (instead of variable `Used` of `add_white` and `add_black` that represent the words already used in the current row). I don't need it any more after having completed a crossword.